# Put a List into natural order. Doesn't work

Tags: java, list, sorting

It is maybe not a good implementation but I want to know why my sorting doesn't work. The only thing I managed is to get rid of the "text" from the list. Maybe it is not a good practise to use list in `sort()` method and I should use an array but I want to see that it can be done with a `List` aswell.

```
public class MyProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Text from TextField.
        String unorderedMixedText = "10 text 2 43 -12 0 41";

        String[] toArrray = unorderedMixedText.split(" ");

        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        // To get only numbers in text.
        for(int i = 0; i < toArrray.length; ) {
           try {
              numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(toArrray[i]));
              i++;
           } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
               i++;
           }
        }
        // Unordered
        Arrays.stream(toArrray).forEach(s -> System.out.print(s + " "));

        // Empty line
        System.out.println();

        sort(numbers);

        // Ordered
        numbers.stream().forEach((number) -> System.out.print(number + " "));
    }

    private static void sort(List<Integer> list) {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size() -1; i++) {
            for(int j = i+1; j < i; j++){
                if(list.get(i) > list.get(j)) {
                    int big = list.get(i);
                    int small = list.get(j);
                    list.set(i, small);
                    list.set(j, big);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I get this output from my program.

```
10 text 2 43 -12 0 41 
10 2 43 -12 0 41
```

Comment: just call `Collections.sort(numbers);`

Comment: "Ready to use code" is always better, but this is for learning purpose. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem in your loop:

```
        for(int j = i+1; j < i; j++){
            if(list.get(i) > list.get(j)) {
                int big = list.get(i);
                int small = list.get(j);
                list.set(i, small);
                list.set(j, big);
            }
```

i+1 is always > i so your loop won't work

Comment: Exactly. you don't enter the inner loop.

Comment: `for(int j = i+1; j < list.size(); j++)` solved my problem! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to your approach, you might like to know about the `Comparator`, which is a class that  you can use for arbitrary comparisons of Collections (like Lists and ArrayLists). For your example, for instance, we could do something like this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {

  public class NaturalNumbers implements Comparator<Integer> {
    // natural comparison is strictly based on what the result
    // of "a minus b" is. So let's just do that!
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
      return a.intValue() - b.intValue();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
  }

  public Test() {
    String s = "1 cats 5432 one two 32 63 12 364 -243 13 lol";
    // turn that into a list of valid Integers:
    List<String> _terms = Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
    ArrayList<Integer> terms = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(String term: _terms) {
       try {
         terms.add(Integer.parseInt(term));
       } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    // sort that list using a natural ordering comparator:
    Collections.sort(terms, new NaturalNumbers());
    System.out.println(terms.toString());
  }
}
```

We define a string list, split it and then discard all the "these are not number" elements, and then we run a natural ordering comparator over the resulting list of Integers. Success, the resulting sorted list starts at -243 and ends in 5432.

In fact, we technically don't even need the Comparator to sort numbers by natural ordering, because without an explicit comparator `Collections.sort(list)` will sort according to natural ordering anyway, but frankly I'm assuming this is homework and tomorrow you're going to be asked to sort this list in a completely different way. Now you know how you'll be able to achieve that.

Comment: Why not just `Collections.sort(terms)` ?

Comment: mostly because if his sorting requirement changes at the drop of a hat (this smells like homework, after all), oxyt now knows enough to do so. Worth pointing out that plain sort()'s natural already in the answer, though.

Comment: Well, you won't need a custom comparator to sort in reverse order either.

Comment: you don't need a comparator for many things, if you're willing to get crafty enough with your preprocessing. I didn't post this answer to get the points for being right, I posted it because the person asking the question deserves to see more than one way to tackle a problem, and the most encompassing way Java lets you do this is comparators. Other people already gave "right" answers.

Comment: Mike thank you for your answer/effort. Its good practise to see an alternative solution aswell. Thank you! :)